# Magento2 API Get email of guest customers in carts endpoint

Tags: cart, email, rest-api, guest-checkout, guest

How can I get the email of a cart created by an guest customer?

In the response for guest carts I get a null in the property customer.email and also a null in the property billing_address.email but the guest user has completed the email in checkout section

Thanks[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you are using default magento guest checkout flow then you must get customer email in "payment-information" api call request data. Please check below screenshot :

[image]

This api call fires when you click on "Place Order" button.

I hope this help to you.

Thanks,